# How to call an .exe from a different folder in Windows command line?

Tags: command-line

For example if I want to run python.exe without being inside the python folder, how can I do this?

I'm here --> C:\

I want to call --> C:\Python27\python

Without having to cd Python27

Answer (score 6):

That would be the following command:

```
C:\Python27\python
```

Comment: lol thanks. I didn't know you needed to call the full path

Comment: And as `Random` mentions below, you don't need the `c:\\` part since that's your current directory, so it doesn't need to be an absolute path.

Comment: @JdeBP: Oh, I missed that. Well, at least this will work anywhere!

Comment: Indeed, it has that advantage.  What M. Takkun needs to know is that `%PATH%` searching occurs when the name has no path prefix (no drive nor directory) at all.  Otherwise the name is taken to be a relative or absolute pathname and is used as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the exe to the system path variable, which will make it available from anywhere in your system.

Go to `System->Environment Variables->Path` (or something similar) and append the path to the end of the list.

May require a restart.

Answer (score 1):

Python27\python.exe
That should do it.